# Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write an EventEmitter in typescript. An error occurs: `Argument of type 'Events.SessionCreationStarting' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`.

```
enum Events {
  SessionCreationStarting,
  SessionCreationSucceeded,
  SessionCreationFailed,
}

type EventMap = Record<string, any>;

type EventKey<T extends EventMap> = string & keyof T;

type EventReceiver<T> = (params: T) => void;

type ListenerMap = Record<string, any>;

type ListenerKey<T extends ListenerMap> = string & keyof T;

class EventEmitter<T extends ListenerMap> {
  _listeners: {
    [K in keyof ListenerMap]?: Array<(p: ListenerMap[K]) => void>;
  } = {}

  on<K extends ListenerKey<T>>(eventName: K, listener: (data: T) => void) {
    this._listeners[eventName] = (this._listeners[eventName] || []).concat(listener);

    return () => {
      this._listeners[eventName] = (this._listeners[eventName] || []).filter(eventListener => listener !== eventListener);
    }
  }

  dispatch<K extends ListenerKey<T>>(eventName: K, data?: T[K]) {
    this._listeners[eventName]?.forEach((fn) => {
      fn.call(null, data);
    });
  }
}

const eventEmmiter = new EventEmitter()

eventEmmiter.dispatch(Events.SessionCreationStarting) <-------- Error
```

## [Code in sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#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-27duJo0RtMZrMNLSInV6wUB+ZQVtzgCEDicHcQs92xbJUH0MoM2CkW1GiFEHuV6RRbzR-YompSYW166TJqCNqY7OaIpdO97sYxg4hsOrLeg0HgwNQZ5DEMDQgHWrqlrB2bUJomhDOAqFvra26lroOG7noYKkL46R6rCcKIiU9wAO7QogsLwlOMwGOu5Hwrs3pHsgJ5QZ0KDegofDkFQKjCEwLCnMxGBAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the values of the members of the `Events` enum are all numbers, as per default behaviour.

What you can do is make your enum a string enum - give each enum member a literal value:

```
enum Events {
  SessionCreationStarting = 'SessionCreationStarting',
  SessionCreationSucceeded = 'SessionCreationSucceeded',
  SessionCreationFailed = 'SessionCreationFailed',
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgZygbwFBSgZWM5ASwHsQBhAJ2AENESQdFqK6QBzKAXigHI8D6lGnVKNmrNjwA0WXPiKkhtejjABjNcGAATHV178F5KstHrNOndNmHBJkSABi1QgBs93PvLvD6zt1YyAL4YGIgAngAOwLAIIIgAstSR+gBKwGrEFNoAPMiIFITsUlDUIOEAfADcoRHRsUgA0sDhOQAqUMAAHoig2qjwSEmRFfr5hexQAGRQANYtxABmUG01YVExg-HpmoQIFO2j3AAUkczUEMgAXCsAlFyjcMSE2mt1MQAyhPmgwBTDaQyWVy4yKbBKZUqbw2UC+PxAf2arQ63V6IH6sO+aL+wyOUFBkxm83CSxWazUrmoBAa8RgEEIiF6BxRPT6qDh2P+yVGmGwAH1XFjfhRruhZNgANqNKBFOYLZYc4XDAC6AH4bgBBCgUaitU43RUIrmRKXK+6cR7PbTVWRBfRoEKyUg5aWotmY+GIlqHCrHYBxRAAOQuwBujRKgs9FBux20tGoNza5stL3uvOwUEQAAtvgA6AVCo3ICX+pDBiDAZX6Y7ZvMFqPF0vxcuVqAAHzbUAlZtzmRAalox0jnNuawzUCoiDAFBAUGOybF4+wteQ+eHwsbAZbVZOK7Xhb+m7LIarHa7PcWbiZfoDhr+Dyg66NUAAhJxuE3EHeKKPxVAQtgjrYNo3xnIgahZi6nSsui7IHhQSI+jex4VmGJRxkw6orKaaZ-nu9ackezYnqquaLFkMDUBBxzHIsIALum450b21CuK4xzgGx6Hxr+45BLx-4YI6fb5J0AZ0vSTL6AiADuNKIHSDLXrcoSfhJDJ-LmIHIGB1FbCgua2Io9gqEwLBgipGBAA)

Comment: Thanks, great solution! But I expected my enum called `Events` to remain "clean"

Comment: Best solution I've found https://github.com/bterlson/strict-event-emitter-types